# Confluent kafka REST proxy returning empty committed offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent REST proxy v.3.2.0 and recently I switched from having auto.commit.enable=true to false and so now I am actively getting and committing the offsets. The goal is to rely on the committed offset each time I create consumers and not on the consumed offset. Reason behind this is that it is very important for us to not skip processing messages in the case when the microservice crashed after consuming messages but in the middle of processing them. Offsets get updated after they have been successfully processed using POST ==> /consumers/(string: group_name)/instances/(string: instance)/offsets. For us, reprocessing messages is not an issue, we get same result so rewinding is tolerated.

The issue is that we are getting empty offsets back in the response to call : GET ==> /consumers/(string: group_name)/instances/(string: instance)/offsets

Why would I get empty offsets in response and what can I do to fix this programmatically? I tried making a call to POST ==> /positions/beginning but that did not help as I still get empty offsets next time I try.

Comment: Has it been more than 24 hours since your apps committed a new offset? Offsets expire every 24 hours by default. You can increase the retention period if needed.

Comment: Thanks @HansJespersen and indeed that is the issue. We need to increase the retention period beyond 24 hrs using property offsets.retention.minutes

Comment: I added official answer for others. Please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With default settings, offsets expire after 24 hours so if you want to keep your position for longer periods of inactivity you need to increase the `offsets.retention.minutes` parameter in the brokers `server.properties` config file.

Otherwise if the offsets expire then the consumer will reset to either beginning or end of the topic depending on the configuration of the reset policy parameter `auto.offset.reset` which is configured in the kafka-rest.properties file.